# Using custom OpenCV build in installed library via CMake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have an issue with a binary that is *installed* via cmake. The binary needs to link to a custom build of OpenCV (in `/home/user/opencv`). The *normal* build of the binary links and runs against the OpenCV just fine. However, the installed version cannot find the OpenCV library that I need.

I do not have much experience with installing binaries via Cmake. So it isn't clear to me whether I am doing something obviously stupid, or whether this is an OpenCV issue.

The minimal example that reproduces the issue looks like this:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(bad_opencv_install)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/cuda-11.4")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(OpenCV_DIR "$ENV{HOME}/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4")
message("OpenCV_DIR = ${OpenCV_DIR}")
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS cudaimgproc)

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC opencv_cudaimgproc)

install(TARGETS foo
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/installed/)
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::cuda::GpuMat mat;
    std::cout << "All good" << std::endl;
}
```

The following shows that the code builds fine:

```
user@xd:~/bad_opencv$ mkdir build ; cd build && cmake .. && make install
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
OpenCV_DIR = /home/user/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda-11.4 (found suitable exact version "11.4") 
-- Found OpenCV: /home/user/opencv (found suitable version "4.6.0", minimum required is "4") found components: cudaimgproc 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/bad_opencv/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable foo
[100%] Built target foo
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/user/bad_opencv/build/installed/foo
-- Set runtime path of "/home/user/bad_opencv/build/installed/foo" to ""
```

Furthermore, the normal build works:

```
user@xd:~/bad_opencv/build$ ./foo
All good
```

But the installed version is not:

```
user@xd:~/bad_opencv/build$ ./installed/foo
./installed/foo: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.406: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
user@xd:~/bad_opencv/build$
```

I don't understand what the `install` command is doing, but if I `ldd` the binary, the installed version is missing a lot of libraries:

```
user@xd:~/bad_opencv/build$ ldd foo
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe7f5e1000)
        libopencv_core.so.406 => /home/user/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.so.406 (0x00007feeee9e8000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007feeee7c2000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007feeee7a7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feeee5b5000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007feeee5af000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feeee58a000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007feeee580000)
        libtbb.so => /home/user/opencv/lib/libtbb.so (0x00007feeee543000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007feeee527000)
        libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007feeee4f3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007feeee3a4000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feef014d000)
        libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007feeee2ea000)
        libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007feeee1ab000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007feeee181000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007feeee17b000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007feeee173000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007feeee157000)


user@xd:~/bad_opencv/build$ ldd ./installed/foo
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd251dc000)
        libopencv_core.so.406 => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3ebad7f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3ebad64000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3ebab72000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3ebaa23000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3ebafac000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: I needed to add the following line to CMake:

```
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

---

Apparently, the runpath is stripped off of the binary when installing. I guess that is what this line of the CMake output was trying to tell me:

```
-- Set runtime path of "/home/user/bad_opencv/build/installed/foo" to ""
```

I determined this by comparing the readelf output:

```
readelf -d ./foo
```

vs

```
readelf -d ./installed/foo
```

The former had some output that looked like

```
0x00000000000000 (RUNPATH) Library runpath: [/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64:/home/user/opencv/lib:]
```

but the latter had no RUNPATH set.

Comment: Yes using `RPATH` is an option here or you can just point LD to the correct libraries by for example specifying the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The issue here is that you are building against the correct libraries, but when you are running the program it does not know where these libraries are. If for example you would do a static build instead it would work without setting up anything.